# Joi - validate strings in mysql datetime format

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I want to validate input strings which are in mysql datetime format like this:
**YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss**
**2018-10-12 19:32:55**

How can I do that?
I have used this code but it allows strings like **222018-10-12 19:32:55** which are invalid.

```
created_at: Joi.date().required()
```

Comment: I think you will find that `YYYY` is pretty much universally interpretted as "Long Year format", meaning `2018` as opposed to just `18` which would typically just be `y`. This is generally because most parsing libraries will adhere to the [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) standards, and `222018` though "far into the future" is actually still valid as a "long year". If you expect something different, you probably want a rule based on a regular expression for the string. So something with `Joi.string().regex()` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of version *v10* `joi.format()` was removed and instead you can use [joi-date-extensions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-date-extensions) 
which provides validation helpers like this:

`Joi.date().format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Comment: This package has been deprecated. Author recomends this one instead `@hapi/joi-date` which seems to be part of a framework.